# 'Userpoints Transactions: Description' doesn't appear in Views

Tags: 7, views, userpoints

I am building a site using Drupal 7 and the User Points module.

I have an original user points page. There I have table with the column "reason". 
[image]

The HTML code for the "Reason" field (same as description?):

```
<td class="userpoints-transactions-field-reason">
<a href="/comment/41#comment-41" title="Commented on New Question for Comments
 6/2/2014.">Commented on New Question f...</a></td>
```

But, I tried to create a new table for transactions in Views.
For some reason, the "Userpoints Transactions: Description" is not showing in views.

Below you can see that the "description" column is empty:
[image]
[image]

This is the HTML code I see in the view:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-description"> 
<span class="views-label views-label-description">Description: </span> 
<span class="field-content"></span>  </div>
```

- why the "Userpoints Transactions: Description" does not shows up
  through views?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'Reason' field: it is named 'Description'. When you're creating a new 'Userpoints Transaction' view, you can simply add a 'Userpoints Transactions: Description' field and everything should work out fine.

**Edit:** I've imported your view and everything works fine on my website. Try reinstalling the User Points and the Views modules and clear caches. Hopefully that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried the "Userpoints Transactions: Description (Description)" - unfortunately, this column output is empty.

Comment: @EB84: Are you granting the userpoints with Rules? If yes, you should add a description for the transaction there.

Comment: But as you can see in my screen-shot, the description already exists. I have many many descriptions on the original page of points. DO I need to create new description If I want to use the same ones on views?

Comment: @EB84: No, normally you can simply use the existing descriptions. Can you perhaps export your view in your question? In that way, it'll be easier for me to find an explanation for the empty output.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I add screenshot of the views settings and output

Comment: @EB84: I've set up a view based on your settings and there's no problem in my case: the descriptions are displayed. Can you export your view, so that I can make sure there's nothing wrong with it?

Comment: I updated the question with the exported code. What do you think?

Comment: I installed views and user points again. I deleted the previous view, and created a new one. Still, under Description I can't see the description under the description fields. It is weird because under the column reason I can see the reasons (on the core "my points" page) but no on views.. Maybe there is another reason?